# If statement doesn't check the condition for an excel cell value in c#

Tags: c#, excel, if-statement, cell

I have the code like above

```
if (worksheet.UsedRange.Cells[rowvalue,columnvalue].Value2.ToString() == "0")
    {
      Statement1
      Statement2
    }
```

It doesn't  recognize the condition i think because it is number. The point is that in excel the number is stored as text. 
[image]

I tried with `.text` but it doesn't check the condition anyway. If i put the same condition for a cell that contains text, like  `if (worksheet.UsedRange.Cells[rowvalue,columnvalue].Text == "sometext")` it recognize the condition.
What can i do at this point? Any Idea?

Comment: So what is the value?

Comment: Well it's clear that `worksheet.UsedRange.Cells[rowvalue,columnvalue].Value2.ToString()` is not equal to the string representation of 0. How can we tell you why that is the case?

Comment: .Value2 gives you the underlying value of the cell (could be empty, string, error, number (double) or boolean)

Comment: We know, but all we can tell you at this point is that whatever value you're getting it's not a string 0. There's simply not enough information to tell you anything else of use.

Comment: I have an excel worksheet witch store all the information in text format, i have to put a condition to make some things. The condition is that the cell must have the 0 value in it to do that some thing. It doesn't recognize the condition. So the problem is the condition, clearly it's a problem of how I put the condition there and for this I need some help.

Comment: No, the condition is absolutely fine as it it. It's clear that whatever value is in that cell is anything but a 0. How can we tell you why that is the case? I suggest you do some debugging and find out what the value really is and why.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, the cell with zero value is represented somehow different. You can just check with Debugger and compare against the result. Regards.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.